# BackboneJS: collection.pluck() in model validation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I want my model to validate for duplicate entry, so I need to access the collection while in the model.

I'm using Backbone.JS together with Require.JS and this makes it a little more confusing.
I can't seem to load my collection as a dependency for the module.

I tried doing validation in the view, but I guess the best practice would be to keep validation in the model where it should be.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Backbone Collection [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add):

> If you're adding models to the collection that are already in the collection, they'll be ignored, unless you pass {merge: true} ...

Which in the `add` -method translates to [this](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-77):

```
if (existing = this.get(model)) {
  if (options.merge) {
    existing.set(attrs === model ? model.attributes : attrs, options);
    if (sort && !doSort && existing.hasChanged(sortAttr)) doSort = true;
  }
  continue;
}
```

Basically that will trump adding any model with duplicate `id`, `cid` or `idAttribute`.

If that isn't enough, then I suggest you do the validation in the view, because bringing a model's collection as a dependency to that exact model would introduce a circular dependency, eg. you need the collection to be able to compile the model, but you also need the model to compile the collection.

So if you need to make sure you're not adding a model to a collection with exactly the same attributes as a model already in that collection, do it in the view. It would look something like this:

```
if (collection.where(modelToBeAdded.toJSON()).length == 0) {
  collection.add(modelToBeAdded);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure doing validation inside the view isn't considered a 'hack-ish' implementation. I actually have two keys, say key1 and key2, which has to be unique in the collection. Let's say a model exists with key1 being 123, and key2 being 456, a new model can't have key1 being 456 and there seems to be no way to do this within the model.